# PHP CSS parser can't parse semicolon in the property values

Tags: php, css, parsing

I'm using this function to parse the CSS files, but when it comes to property values containing semicolon, it breaks. Example:

```
#logo {
    background-image: url("data:image/png;base64,..................");
}
```

I changed the explode delimiter to "\n" but it didn't produce expected results.
Please help.

Function:

```
function parse($file){
    $css = file_get_contents($file);
    preg_match_all( '/(?ims)([a-z0-9\s\.\:#_\-@,]+)\{([^\}]*)\}/', $css, $arr);
    $result = array();
    foreach ($arr[0] as $i => $x){
        $selector = trim($arr[1][$i]);
        $rules = explode(';', trim($arr[2][$i]));
        $rules_arr = array();
        foreach ($rules as $strRule){
            if (!empty($strRule)){
                $rule = explode(":", $strRule);
                $rules_arr[trim($rule[0])] = trim($rule[1]);
            }
        }

        $selectors = explode(',', trim($selector));
        foreach ($selectors as $strSel){
            $result[$strSel] = $rules_arr;
        }
    }
    return $result;
}
```

Execution:

```
$css = parse('content/custom.css');
echo print_r($css);
```

Comment: what is the method supposed to do? what is the difference between your `parse` function and echoing the css file directly? It's not immediately obvious from the code

Comment: @chiliNUT: this method provides array, and it's not the same as echo.   `[#logo] => Array
        (
            [background-image] => url("data
            [base64,...................")] => 
            [background-size] => auto 100%
        )`. I'm trying to get the valid property value for `background-image`. =)

Comment: I'll just leave this here: https://github.com/sabberworm/PHP-CSS-Parser

Comment: @prodigitalson: i already tried sabberworm, it's like a tank and requires some other libraries. I don't need a tank for simple parsing...

Answer (score 0):

What about using a temporary place holder string for the offsensive `;base64`, then do the split, then restore it back, something like:

Replace this line:

```
 $rules = explode(';', trim($arr[2][$i]));
```

with this:

```
//replace ;base64 with a placeholder
$placeholder=uniqid();
$arr[2][$i] = str_replace(";base64",$placeholder,$arr[2][$i]);
//explode
$rules = explode(';', trim($arr[2][$i]));
//restore from placeholder
$rules = array_map(function ($el) {
    return str_replace($placeholder, ";base64", $el);
}, $rules);
```

Comment: What if there will be something else instead of `base64`? This is not very reliable solution... =)

Comment: what other exceptions are there where a semi-colon does not denote the end of a style, other than ;base64?

Comment: oh i guess inside of a `content: ` rule would be another

Comment: The ideal way will be to get the property value between `:` and `;\n` (line break).

Comment: @Radio what if im a crazy bastard that routinely writes styles on a single line like `some-selector { margin: 0 auto; background-image: url("data:image/png;base64,.................."); }`? ;-)

Comment: @prodigitalson: well, then you'll need to change your approaches... =))